# Column 'encrypted_password' cannot be null?

Tags: java, sql, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

Im working on a web service using `Java` and `spring-data-jpa`. I setted different endpoints that works fine. Now I implemented logics in the post method and get return an error that I can't solve.

I use `postman` and when I try to make a post request with id,username,lastname and password i get an error 500 and the server return me this error:

> java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'encrypted_password' cannot be null

```
package com.nicolacannata.Appws.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity(name="users")
public class UserEntity implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8076405899207283205L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String userId;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String encryptedPassword;

    private String emailVerificationToken;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean emailVerificationStatus = false;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getEncryptedPassword() {
        return encryptedPassword;
    }

    public void setEncryptedPassword(String encryptedPassword) {
        this.encryptedPassword = encryptedPassword;
    }

    public String getEmailVerificationToker() {
        return emailVerificationToken;
    }

    public void setEmailVerificationToker(String emailVerificationToker) {
        this.emailVerificationToken = emailVerificationToker;
    }

    public boolean isEmailVerificationStatus() {
        return emailVerificationStatus;
    }

    public void setEmailVerificationStatus(boolean emailVerificationStatus) {
        this.emailVerificationStatus = emailVerificationStatus;
    }
}
```

Comment: The exception is thrown because you delcared the column `encryptedPassword` to be not `null` (`@Column(..., nullable = false)`). The root cause is most probably because you do not set is (properly). Without seeing your endpoint, the logic constructing the entity to create and your POST request, it is hard to further diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared that attribute `encryptedPassword` cannot be null. The exception means, that this attribute was `null` when you attempted to save it to database. Either you forgot to set this attribute. Or you set it (you called setter), but the new value was `null`. To resolve the problem, set this attribute to a `not-null` value before saving to DB.

Answer (score 1):

You have `@Column(nullable = false)` for `private String encryptedPassword;` and you are passing only *id, username, lastname and password*. which breaks the condition `nullable = false` and results in `java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'encrypted_password' cannot be null`

**Solution**

Set `@Column(nullable = true)`

OR

Pass the value for `encryptedPassword`